# Can I expire all sessions of a user?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

Can I expire all sessions of a user?
I know that I can expire a `session` by using `session.invalidate()`.

I am using Tomcat, servlet/JSP.

In a session I have a attribute `userId`.

On that basis we define that this `session` belongs to a particular user.

I have a need in which I have to invalidate all sessions containing a particular userId.

Comment: You can create a `HttpSessionListener` and add each created session to some `List` and put it in `context`. Then iterate through the `List` to get each `session` check for its attribute and `invalidate()` !!!!

Comment: You can make all session value empty..

Answer (score 6):

Use [this code](http://www.coderanch.com/t/365859/Servlets/java/session-object-session-ID) to manage your active sessions and get a session by its Id, then you can call this session and invalidate it once needed:

```
 public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener  
{  

     private static Map<String, HttpSession> map = new   
                                     HashMap<String, HttpSession>();  

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event)  
    {  
        String id = event.getSession().getId();  
        logger.debug("session created : " + id);  
        // STORE THE SESSOIN FOR EXAMPLE IN DATABASE 
        map.put(id, event.getSession());  
    }  

    public static HttpSession getHttpSession(String sessionID)  
    {  
        return sessionObjectMap.get(sessionID);  
    }  

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event)  
    {  
        // get the destroying session...               
    }  
}
```

Comment: Good answer votedup. . .sessionDestroyed() is over loaded and called every time we destroy session.  . can we overload it only when we want to destroy all sessions

Comment: It's in the HttpSessionListener interface, you must implement it, at least the declaration.

Comment: The code is not thread-safe since HashMap is not a thread-safe class.
Also, the "map" is never clearned so the sessions will stay in memory forever causing a memory-leak.

Comment: reply to a similar question,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276554/spring-security-how-to-expire-all-sessions-of-a-user/35276555#35276555

Answer (score 1):

make a listner by implementing `HttpSessionListener` and add each created session to a data structure. . like Map or list

for Map use `SessionId as Key` and `session object` as value. . . .

Override both `sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event)` and `sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event)`

`sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event)` method is called when any session is created by container. . and we can do what ever we want to do with it at this creation time. . like add in list or map

`sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event)` is called when ever a session is destroyed or invalidated(either by code or timed out by server).  . we can do what ever with it before destroy. . . like total logged time. . remove from list or map. . etc

Answer (score 0):

You can make all session value empty..

```
session.removeAttribute("userId");
```